# Android - Add Vuforia SDK to existing android studio project

Tags: android, frameworks, augmented-reality, vuforia, android-augmented-reality

I want to make a small Augmented Reality Android app, using the Image Marker functionality from the Vuforia Framework.

I have downloaded the SDK and the Sample project and set it all up. It all works fine, after a long working process.

Now I want to create a new project and add the Image Marker session when you press a button. But I have no clue which files I should import, get only the framework working with the Image Marker session into my own app.

I have looked the documentation through, but I can only find information on how to set up the sample project. Can anyone help me with importing Vuforia to my own project?

Comment: https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk

Comment: I have the SDK downloaded. I just dont know, how to integrate it with a new app and use the functionality

Comment: on another note, you can use EasyAR sdk for augmented reality in android studio. They have tutorials available for integration

Comment: Yea i know, and i am really considering it. The Vuforia dokumentation is so bad. The problem is that i already have a iOS version of my app, using Vuforia and i would like to stay consistant. But maybe it is where we are, i am so tired of the Vuforia integration

Comment: vuforia sdk is good for unity and has lots of tutorial too but for android they have nothing

Comment: I am not an Android Developer but why don't you consider ARCore since you already have the Android Studio Project. You can start a new Session with click of a button

Comment: ARCore has a very limited number of available devices.. I listened to @VivekMishra and thanks to him i now have a fully functional Android app using EasyAR - Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Importing Vuforia Core Samples:**

-Go to the asset store and search for the "Vuforia Core Samples" package or click this link.
-Download and import the package.
-Note: Vuforia Core Samples form a complete project and will overwrite the current project. We recommend you import Vuforia Core Samples into an empty project
-Enable "Vuforia Augmented Reality Supported" in "XR Settings" of Unity's Player Settings.

Comment: So i should make the Augmented Reality functionality in Unity and then import it to Android studio? But can the Unity AR then communicate with the rest of the app?